# VirtualBox Windows Server 2016 Failed Setup - Media Driver Missing. Possible Corrupted ISO file?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, download, iso-image

I've been trying to install Windows Server 2016 in Virtual Box for a while now. Although I can't seem to get it to work at all. I install everything normally, using all default settings. I only change storage and ram amount. I can get it to boot up inside the VM, reaching all the way till the set-up button. This is where I get issues. After I click set up and it finishes loading, I get the generic "Media Driver Missing" notification/pop up.

I looked around and tried a solution of downloading the VB Guest Additions. It didn't work either. So, at this point I assume that somehow, my iso file is corrupted, didn't download everything fully, or isn't Official. I heavily doubt the former to be what is causing it as I downloaded the file straight from Microsoft themselves.

After this, I went back into the Microsoft site and attempted to download the Windows Server 2019 version instead, thinking it might work this time. That was when I noticed something strange pop up in the save as portion when getting the prompt to download it.

[Corrupted symbols in Saveas box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tburc.png)

I believe this might be the issue but I'm not completely convinced. When I save the file and download it, it saves normally as an iso and continues to download normally as well.

From testing with other downloads off the web,  ONLY AND EVERYONE of the iso type file extension causes this weird matrix of characters to appear in the saveas box when downloading. Every other file extension appears as normal (exe,rar, etc.). I've only noticed this issue as of today.

I have no idea what could be causing either one of these issues, but I'm more concerned on getting the VM up and running with the server properly setting up. Thank you.

P.S. - My Windows Server 2019 file comes up as 4.9 GB in download manager and Windows 2016 Server came up at 6.5 GB in download manager.

Comment: You cannot really compare the size of the ISO of two entirely different versions of Windows Server without mounting them within Windows and using DISM list which images are contained on them.  I mention this fact, in the event, you are using their size to determine anything of significance